# How can i update a field of a ListItem (LiveData)

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

How can i update a field of a ListItem?

I have following POJO and ViewModel classes. Currently i am getting the complete list from LiveData object and then updating its data then re-setting the value of LiveData object, But I don't think this is the correct way to do it because to update just name of a single book i have to reset the complete LiveData Object.

Any other suggestion or Good practice to do it the correct way?

```
public class Book {

        private long id;
        private String name;

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
}

public class BookProvider extends AndroidViewModel {

        private final MutableLiveData<List<Book>> booksData;

        public BookProvider(@NonNull Application application) {
            super(application);
            booksData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }

        public LiveData<List<Book>> getBooksData() {
            return booksData;
        }

        public void updateBookName(int position, String name) {
            final List<Book> books = booksData.getValue();
            if (books != null && books.size() > position) {
                books.get(position).setName(name);
            }
            booksData.setValue(books);
        }
}
```

Comment: your approach is ok, do you have any performance problems with it?

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I hadn't noticed any performance issue yet, but resetting the complete object...
May be i am thinking too much about it.

I think i should keep it as it is.

Comment: if you see `LiveData` sources `setValue()` method is not expensive at all: it just sets the reference, so you should not worry about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LiveData` is just a **container** holding a **reference** to your data and **notifying** possible observer of changes. So as far as `LiveData` is concerned this is the best you can do.

However `LiveData` does't support **molecular** changes so every change may results in the entire list invalidating and redrawn. It is strongly suggested that you use a different method if you have lot of changes in data (like **real-time** applications).

Comment: `DiffUtil` are used more for animation purposes when adding/updating/removing items from `RecyclerView` - they dont improve performance - i would say that `DiffUtil#calculateDif` is a rather costly method when it comes to CPU usage

Comment: Google says that this is [intended behavior](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77363656) and strongly recommends using DiffUtil or a custom List implementation

Comment: Exactly, the easiest way would be using ListAdapter (RecyclerView's one not ListView's) which implement DiffUtills.